# How to stop propagation from webview load events on nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Stopping the propagation is the "key" here, but just for illustrate better my scenario:

```
loadStarted(event: LoadEventData) {

event.preventDefault();//does not work, just for demonstration

let webview = <WebView>event.object;

webview.src = newUrl;

... }
```

When the redirecting (from webview) *starts* i want capture the url, stop the propagation from this event (does not redirect to the current url itself, only capture some info that comes in this url from the server (using oAuth2) and redirect the user to another url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both iOS and Android has a `stopLoading` method which will work nicely here:

```
if (ios) {
    event.object.ios.stopLoading();
} else if (android) {
    event.object.android.stopLoading();
}
```

Comment: Are you kidding? There is no such an `object` property on my Android

Comment: @alsotang you're commenting on a more than 5 year old answer. However, the answer gives you more than enough information to quickly lookup the current implementation. https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_web_view_.webview.html#stoploading

Comment: My fault. I thought it is a answer against web development. I am not familiar with nativescript.